# How to run GUI related code in GNU Smalltalk?

Tags: smalltalk, gnu-smalltalk

I have the following code form Dolphin Smalltalk:

```
digitalClockProcess := [[

       Processor sleep: 1000.

       (View desktop canvas)

               font: (Font name: 'Arial' pointSize: 36) beBold;

               text: Time now printString at: 10@10;

               free

] repeat] fork.
```

which shows a digital clock on the desktop.  Can this code be run on GNU Smalltalk?  I tried `gst` and `gst-blox` on Fedora on a VirtualBox VM and it didn't work, and `gst-blox` doesn't exist on Ubuntu, and `gst-browser` on both Fedora and Ubuntu gave a

> Object: CFunctionDescriptor new: 1 "<0x7ffb3a010dc0>" error: Invalid C call-out g_date_get_type

when starting up the app.  How is it done in GNU Smalltalk?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not familiar with GNU Smalltalk (I use Pharo), so maybe there is better way to write the code, but regardless.

## Installation

`gst` installed from package manager doesn't need any GUI (it's a CLI), and even though it offers them, it doesn't pull the necessary system libraries to run them, so you have to install them [manually](http://smalltalk.gnu.org/blog/zuluuuuuu/installing-gnu-smalltalk-ubuntu-10-10):

- for `gst-browser` (new ui): `libgtk2.0` `libcairo2` (tested on ubuntu)
- for `gst-blox` (old ui): `tcl` `tk` (not tested)

## Code

I see two problems with the code: GST doesn't support `Process>>sleep:`, and it uses GUI.

As for GUI, Smalltalks have very different UI libraries, Dolphin is geared towards MS Windows, GNU Smalltalk uses GNU stuff (GTK for the newser gst-browser, and TK/TCL for older gst-blox it seems), Pharo uses Athens, etc. Even if they share some concepts (such as MVC pattern), they do not really share API.

In fact it seems that GNUSmalltalk has "new" UI --- VisualGST (gst-browser) and that gst-blox is deprecated.

In any case, after some digging I end up with the following code. It creates a GTK window (UI used by gst-browser), and then it continuously updates the text.

```
window := GTK.GtkWindow new: GTK.Gtk gtkWindowToplevel.
window setTitle: 'Time'.
window resize: 400 height: 300.
label := GTK.GtkLabel new.
label setText: Time now printString.
label show.
window add: label.
window show.

digitalClockProcess := [[
    (Delay forSeconds: 1) wait.
    label setText: Time now printString.
] repeat] fork.
```

The code for `gst-blox` would have to use tcl/tk instead, which I am not familiar with.

## Running the code

To run the code in `gst-browser`, from top menu select 'Tools > Bottom Pane', and then paste the code to a 'Workspace' that will be in the bottom pane (you can add more workspaces via 'File > New Workspace'.

Comment: so I assume the code is to be run in `gst-blox`?   but if on Fedora and `gst-blox` I run the first line `window := GTK.GtkWindow new: GTK.Gtk gtkWindowToplevel.` it will say: "invalid scope resolution" (and `gst` won't run the code either)

Comment: This code is for gst-browser (the newer IDE), I can look how this is done in gst-blox, but I am not familiar with tcl/tk

Comment: How do you start up `gst-browser`? I can't do it on Fedora or Ubuntu as in the question

Answer (score 0):

Instructions how to download and build GNU smalltalk can be found [here](http://smalltalk.gnu.org/download). This should solve your problem with the availability of gst-blox (GNU smalltalk with GUI) on ubuntu.

Comment: `gst-blox` on Fedora couldn't run those code... so I don't think Ubuntu would make any difference